# Не получается разбить JSON файл после LongPollServer запроса

Tags: c#

Делаю бота для ВК на С#. Сделал LongPollServer запрос. Пришел json файл. Он не null, информация в нем выводится в консоль без проблем.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только я хочу распарсить этот файл и добраться до key,server and ts, прилетает ошибка.
Вот код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку!

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо проверять на null, каждое из полей объекта "responceLongPoll", а так же вместо типа dynamic используйте явно JObject.